# How many tables a dataverse can have in power platform?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dataverse, power-platform

How many tables a dataverse can have in power platform?
How many rows and columns a table can have in dataverse?

I searched in Google. It provided many answers and I got confused. Please help me to find out the right answers

Answer (score 0):

*[Maximum number of tables that can be created in dataverse](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Dataverse/Maximum-number-of-tables-that-can-be-created-in-dataverse/td-p/1611993)*

---

There is no specified limit on the number of tables for Dataverse. You can refer to the [SQL Server limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) since relational data is stored there.

SQL doesn't impose a limit on number of tables, but instead the number of total database objects (~2 Billion).

There is a limit of 1024 columns per table that you should be aware of, but otherwise you will exceed your Dataverse storage capacity long before you hit any metadata limits.

Comment: Incorrect, there is actually a limit.

Answer (score 0):

For Dataverse there is actually a limit to the number of tables that can be created. Navigate to https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/environments.

Then:

- Select an environment;
- Click `Settings` on the command bar;
- Choose `Resources` and `All legacy settings`;
- On the legacy settings page navigate to Administration;
- From the menu select feature `Resources In Use`.

In my case I can create 3,000 entities (tables), but this may vary depending on your plan.

See also [Limitations on creating metadata items - MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/create-edit-metadata#limitations-on-creating-metadata-items).

For the **maximum number of columns per table** SQL Server limitations apply. From the article referenced above: *"Within each table there's an upper limit on the number of columns you can create. This limit is based on the technical limitations on the amount of data that can be stored in a row of a database table."*

Concerning the **maximum size of the database**: I remember a limit of 4TB has been mentioned in documentation, but I *know* special arrangements can be made when really needed. In reality databases that are multiple terabytes in size are not easy to handle in the cloud.

Comment: That is your plan limitation for _tables_ count. Not physical limit of OP question _How many **rows and columns** a table can have in dataverse_

Comment: OP is not asking for physical limitations. For Dataverse limitations are set by the platform no matter what the limits of SQL Server are. For columns indeed the limits of SQL Server apply and that is mentioned in the reference documentation on MS Learn. For the database 4 TB is often mentioned, but is probably not a hard limit. I extended my answer. (Do not understand why you should downvote my post though, i.m.o. it is correct and adds valuable information.)